# What does *--a = *--b mean in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence, pointer-arithmetic

Suppose `a` and `b` are pointers,

My understanding is `*--a = *--b` means subtract 1 from `a` and `b` using pointer arithmetic, then dereference `a` and `b` and set them equal.

Is this equivalent to

```c
--a;
--b;
*a=*b
```

Similarly, what is

```c
*a++ = *b++;
```

equivalent to?

Comment: Your understanding of `*--a = *--b` is correct. And `*a++ = *b++` shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: The first is equivalent to what you suggest (`*--a = *--b;` is equivalent to `--a; --b; *a = *b;` — the question got edited a lot, hence I'm repeating what I'm commenting on).  The second (`*a++ = *b++;`) is equivalent to `*a = *b; a++; b++`.

Comment: But what if `a == b`?

Comment: Post increment. Same principle as your first example except it happens after the expression is evaluated.

Comment: @G.Sliepen — what about it?  The code is well-formed and deterministic as long as the pointers are pointing somewhere valid at the time that they're dereferenced.  That means the pre-decremented pointers shouldn't be pointing before the beginning of an array, so neither pointer should be pointing to the start of an array before the expression is evaluated.  (If, perchance, you mean `*--a = *--a;`, then you're into undefined behaviour — no one would have the slightest clue what is expected to happen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*––a = *––b
```

is *logically* equivalent to

```
tmpa = a - 1
tmpb = b - 1
*tmpa = *tmpb
a = a - 1
b = b - 1
```

with the caveat that the updates to `a`, `b`, and `*tmpa` can occur *in any order*, and those updates can even be interleaved.  It’s also possible for the implementation to skip the temporaries and update the pointer values immediately:

```
a = a - 1
b = b - 1
*a = *b
```

but that’s not required or guaranteed.  Similarly,

```
*a++ = *b++
```

is logically equivalent to

```
tmpa = a
tmpb = b
*tmpa = *tmpb
a = a + 1
b = b + 1
```

with the same caveats about the ordering of the updates to `a`, `b`, and `*tmpa`.  Again, the implementation may skip using temporaries and evaluate it as

```
*a = *b
a = a + 1
b = b + 1
```

but again that’s neither required nor guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

`*a++ = *b++;`

dereference `b` and assign it to where `a` points. The `++` is the postfix operator, so the current value of `*b` will be assigned to `*a`, then both will be incremented.

If you keep this in a `while` loop,  all the characters from `b` will be copied to `a` including the `\0`. This continues as long as `*a++ = *b++` is not `\0`, at which time loop terminates.

`while(*a++ = *b++);`

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a_arr[30]  = {0};
    char b_arr[] = "Hello,World";
    
    char *a = a_arr;
    char *b = b_arr;
    
    while(*a++ = *b++);
    
    puts(a_arr);
    puts(b_arr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
uint8_t *a = 1030; // POINTS TO ADDRESS 1030
uint8_t *b = 1020; // POINTS TO ADDRESS 1020

printf("%d", *(--a)); // PRINTS VALUE ON ADDRESS 1029
printf("%d", *(b++)); // PRINTS VALUE ON ADDRESS 1021
```

`*(--a)` subtracts one byte(one address) because pointer `a` points to one byte(it is `uint8_t`). After subtraction, it will read value from address.

`*(--something)` you can write as

```
uint32_t *c = 1050;
c -= 1; // SUBCTRACTS 4 BYTE ADDRESS FROM POINTER c
print("%d", *c);
```

Why 4 bytes you may ask? Because pointer `c` points to four byte(`uint32_t` or `int32_t`) data. You can get size of data in bytes with `sizeof(variable)`.

In your case, lets say pointer `a` points to address `40`. Pointer `b` points to address 50.

- Address `39` holds value `1`
- Address `40` holds value `2`
- Address `50` holds value `10`
- Address `51` holds value `11`

  ```
   uint8_t *a = 40;
   uint8_t *b = 50;

   printf("%d", *(--a));
   printf("%d", *(b++));
  ```

First `printf` will print value `1`. Second `printf` will print value `50`.
After `printf` pointer `a` points to address `39` and pointer `b` points to address `51`

Reason? In first `printf`, it will first subctract one address(again, one because it points to one byte value), and then it will dereference value(that is why we use `*` for reading the value from pointer address).

In second `printf`, it will first dereference value and then move pointer one address up.